# Using extension methods from a separate class library in T4

Tags: visual-studio-2015, t4

I created a class library with extension methods for working with `EnvDTE` objects. An example extension method is:

```
namespace EnvDTE.Extensions
{
    public static class DTEExtensions
    {
        public static Project CurrentProject (this DTE dte)
        {
            return dte.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject;
        }
    }
}
```

when I attempt to use the extension method in my T4 file:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ assembly name = "$(SolutionDir)..\..\Windows\EnvDTE.Extensions\EnvDTE.Extensions\bin\Debug\EnvDTE.Extensions.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name = "System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE.Extensions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    var serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
    var dte = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE; 
    var project = dte.CurrentProject();
#>
namespace <#= project.Properties.Item("DefaultNamespace").Value #>
{

}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Running transformation: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Cannot load type 'EnvDTE._DTE, EnvDTE.Extensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.MethodCall.ResolveMethod(Boolean bThrowIfNotResolved)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.MethodCall..ctor(SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMsg, ArrayList deserializedArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at EnvDTE._DTE.get_ActiveDocument()
   at EnvDTE.Extensions.DTEExtensions.CurrentProject(DTE dte) in D:\Users\Adaptive\Projects\Windows\EnvDTE.Extensions\EnvDTE.Extensions\DTEExtensions.cs:line 13
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0BE14095FFF8852C1DA8AAA0F831675849ECBB71E2A8B8BA2027BD64107CEDE73824E8CF863A0048B6B5FF80E64944B13E838B3338BD67CA7B6A2CF9BB4BD07C.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() TicketTracker   D:\Users\Adaptive\Projects\Universal\TicketTracker\TicketTracker\Models\HoursModel.tt   1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? It appears the transformation engine is looking for types in the wrong library. I know I could create a collection of my extension methods by importing various T4 files, but I prefer a class library if I can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that the assembly with my extension methods was embedding Interop types. I had to turn that off for my extension methods to work:

[image: Embed Interop Types: False]

[Credits to Microsoft Support](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/484a7c26-af73-4b04-a118-dfdc57d7d1eb/using-extension-methods-from-a-separate-class-library-in-t4?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Comment: please if this solved your problem, mark this answer as accepted to help other find the correct answer quickly

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but according to this [blog post](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/02/t4-template-directive/) when you set the language attribute to "C#" or "VB" T4 will use the 2.0 framework but if you use "C#v3.5" or "VBv3.5" it will use the 3.5 framework which should allow you to use extension methods.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for help on leveraging extension methods. The extension method actually gets executed, but the runtime gets confused as it tries to locate: `EnvDTE._DTE` interface inside my custom `EnvDTE.Extensions`  assembly. The interface is actually located inside the `EnvDTE` assembly.